# What is an elegant way to solve this max and min problem in Ruby or Python?

Tags: python, ruby

The following can be done by step by step, somewhat clumsy way, but I wonder if there are elegant method to do it.

There is a page: http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii, where there are 2 tables... there is

```
Mario    -   6   2   2   3   -   -
Luigi    2   6   -   -   -   -   -
Diddy Kong   -   -   3   -   3   -   5
  [...]
```

The name "Mario", etc are the Mario Kart Wii character names.
The numbers are for bonus points for:

```
Speed    Weight  Acceleration    Handling    Drift   Off-Road    Mini-Turbo
```

and then there is table 2

```
Standard Bike S 39  21  51  51  54  43  48  
Bullet Bike 53  24  32  35  67  29  67      
Bubble Bike / Jet Bubble    48  27  40  40  45  35  37  
  [...]
```

These are also the characteristics for the Bike or Kart.

I wonder what's the most elegant solution for finding all the maximum combinations of Speed, Weight, Acceleration, etc, and also for the minimum, either by directly using the HTML on that page or copy and pasting the numbers into a text file.

Actually, in that character table, Mario to Bower Jr are all medium characters, Baby Mario to Dry Bones are small characters, and the rest are all big characters, except the small, medium, or large Mii are just as what the name says.  Small characters can only ride small bike or small kart, and so forth for medium and large.

**Update:** it would be nice to also filter out only Kart type or Bike when printing the results, as some people only play with bikes, and only for the "in" or "out" drift type for the bikes, as some people only play using "in" drift type.  Also nice is to print out result that have the same max or min value (different characters on different kart or bike that add up to the same value).  Hugh's answer of printing out top values and bottom values is nice too as some of values are quite close, such as 73 or 72.

Comment: Now I want to play Mario Kart again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two parts to your problem. Parsing the HTML, and doing the analysis. Parsing the HTML is a tedious job and I suspect there's not a whole lot that you can do to make it elegant. The analysis is not hard, but there are some ways to do this in Python that I think might be considered elegant. I'm going to discuss ways to express the brute force analysis in an elegant and concise fashion. I'm not going to discuss ways to do it faster than brute force because the data set is so tiny.

```
import collections

Stats = collections.namedtuple("Stats", "speed weight acceleration handling drift offroad turbo")
```

First up we make a named tuple called "Stats". This is the object we will use to represent the stats of a driver or vehicle. Named tuples are nice because:

- They can be defined very concisely.
- They provide a constructor that just takes the fields in order.
- They let us access any field by name, e.g. `driver.weight`
- They provide an easy to read `__str__` format: `"Stats(speed=73, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16)"`
- They can be accessed as a sequence, just like a regular tuple.

Let's define a function to add two sets of stats:

```
def add_stats(xs, ys):
    return Stats(*[(x+y) for (x,y) in zip(xs,ys)])
```

Zip takes two sequences and returns a sequence of pairs of items from each sequence. E.g. zip([1,2,3], ['a','b','c']) == [(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c')]). Then we use a list comprehension (`[blah for blah in blah]`) to add together the stats from each of these pairs. Finally we feed that to the Stats constructor. The * means that we want to use each item in the sequence as an argument to the function.

```
class ThingWithStats(object):
    def __init__(self, name, stats):
        self.name = name
        self.stats = Stats(*stats)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " (" + str(self.stats) + ")"

class Driver(ThingWithStats):
    pass

class Vehicle(ThingWithStats):
    pass

class Combination(ThingWithStats):
    def __init__(self, driver, vehicle):
        self.name = driver.name + " riding " + vehicle.name
        self.stats = add_stats(driver.stats, vehicle.stats)
```

Now we have defined classes to represent drivers, vehicles and combinations of the two. Note that the constructors for Driver and Vehicle (inherited from ThingWithStats) can take any sequence of the appropriate length as their `stats` argument. They use a `*` to convert the sequence into a `Stats` object. We'll see why this is handy shortly.

```
def make_combinations(drivers, vehicles):
    return [
        Combination(driver, vehicle)
        for driver in drivers
        for vehicle in vehicles]
```

This function uses a list comprehension to find all combinations of some list of drivers and some list of vehicles. Note that by using multiple "for"s in a single comprehension we get *all combinations*. This is also sometimes called a Cartesian product.

Now here's the tediuous bit - the data. I copied and pasted these and used some vim magic to massage them into the correct format. Sorry I don't have anything more clever for this. Note that for the `stats` argument we pass a regular tuple. As mentioned above, the constructor converts with into a `Stats` object. This saves us a little clutter here.

```
medium_drivers = [
    Driver("Mario",        (0, 6, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Luigi",        (2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Peach",        (2, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Daisy",        (4, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3)),
    Driver("Yoshi",        (0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 5, 0)),
    Driver("Birdo",        (0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 5)),
    Driver("Diddy Kong",   (0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 5)),
    Driver("Bowser Jr.",   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3)),
    Driver("Medium Mii",   (3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3)),
    ]

small_drivers = [
    Driver("Baby Mario",   (0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Baby Luigi",   (5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Baby Peach",   (3, 6, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Baby Daisy",   (5, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3)),
    Driver("Toad",         (0, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 0)),
    Driver("Toadette",     (3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0)),
    Driver("Koopa Troopa", (0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6)),
    Driver("Dry Bones",    (0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 6)),
    Driver("Small Mii",    (3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3)),
    ]

large_drivers = [
    Driver("Wario",        (0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6)),
    Driver("Waluigi",      (0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 3, 0)),
    Driver("Donkey Kong",  (0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3)),
    Driver("Bowser",       (2, 5, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0)),
    Driver("King Boo",     (0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 3, 0)),
    Driver("Rosalina",     (3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3)),
    Driver("Funky Kong",   (4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0)),
    Driver("Dry Bowser",   (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 6)),
    Driver("Large Mii",    (3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3)),
    ]

small_vehicles = [
    Vehicle("Standard Kart S",             (41, 29, 48, 48, 51, 40, 45)),
    Vehicle("Baby Booster / Booster Seat", (27, 27, 56, 64, 37, 54, 59)),
    Vehicle("Concerto / Mini Beast",       (55, 32, 29, 32, 64, 27, 64)),
    Vehicle("Cheep Charger",               (34, 24, 64, 56, 59, 45, 54)),
    Vehicle("Rally Romper / Tiny Titan",   (46, 35, 43, 43, 29, 64, 40)),
    Vehicle("Blue Falcon",                 (60, 29, 35, 29, 43, 24, 29)),

    Vehicle("Standard Bike S",             (39, 21, 51, 51, 54, 43, 48)),
    Vehicle("Bullet Bike",                 (53, 24, 32, 35, 67, 29, 67)),
    Vehicle("Nano Bike / Bit Bike",        (25, 18, 59, 67, 40, 56, 62)),
    Vehicle("Quacker",                     (32, 17, 67, 60, 62, 48, 57)),
    Vehicle("Magikruiser",                 (43, 24, 45, 45, 32, 67, 43)),
    Vehicle("Bubble Bike / Jet Bubble",    (48, 27, 40, 40, 45, 35, 37)),
    ]

medium_vehicles = [
    Vehicle("Standard Kart M",                (46, 45, 40, 43, 45, 35, 40)),
    Vehicle("Nostalgia 1 / Classic Dragster", (37, 43, 59, 54, 54, 40, 51)),
    Vehicle("Wild Wing",                      (57, 51, 21, 29, 59, 24, 59)),
    Vehicle("Turbo Blooper / Super Blooper",  (50, 40, 35, 37, 21, 54, 35)),
    Vehicle("Royal Racer / Daytripper",       (34, 45, 51, 59, 32, 48, 54)),
    Vehicle("B Dasher Mk. 2 / Sprinter",      (64, 48, 27, 24, 37, 21, 24)),

    Vehicle("Standard Bike M",                (43, 37, 43, 45, 48, 37, 43)),
    Vehicle("Mach Bike",                      (55, 37, 24, 32, 62, 27, 62)),
    Vehicle("Bon Bon / Sugarscoot",           (32, 32, 54, 62, 35, 51, 56)),
    Vehicle("Rapide / Zip Zip",               (41, 35, 45, 51, 29, 62, 45)),
    Vehicle("Nitrocycle / Sneakster",         (62, 40, 29, 27, 40, 24, 27)),
    Vehicle("Dolphin Dasher",                 (48, 43, 37, 40, 24, 56, 37)),
    ]

large_vehicles = [
    Vehicle("Standard Kart L",              (48, 59, 37, 40, 40, 35, 35)),
    Vehicle("Offroader",                    (39, 64, 48, 54, 18, 43, 45)),
    Vehicle("Flame Flyer",                  (62, 59, 16, 21, 48, 18, 48)),
    Vehicle("Piranha Prowler",              (55, 67, 29, 35, 35, 29, 27)),
    Vehicle("Aero Glider / Jetsetter",      (69, 56, 21, 17, 27, 16, 16)),
    Vehicle("Dragonetti / Honeycoupe",      (53, 62, 27, 29, 56, 24, 56)),

    Vehicle("Standard Bike L",              (46, 54, 40, 43, 43, 37, 37)),
    Vehicle("Bowser Bike / Flame Runner",   (60, 54, 18, 24, 51, 21, 51)),
    Vehicle("Wario Bike",                   (37, 59, 51, 56, 21, 45, 48)),
    Vehicle("Twinkle Star / Shooting Star", (50, 48, 29, 32, 59, 27, 59)),
    Vehicle("Torpedo / Spear",              (67, 56, 24, 18, 29, 18, 18)),
    Vehicle("Phantom",                      (43, 51, 43, 48, 17, 56, 40)),
    ]
```

With that out of the way, we make lists of all the combinations:

```
small_combinations = make_combinations(small_drivers, small_vehicles)
medium_combinations = make_combinations(medium_drivers, medium_vehicles)
large_combinations = make_combinations(large_drivers, large_vehicles)

all_combinations = small_combinations + medium_combinations + large_combinations
```

Finally we do some basic analysis on the list of all combinations:

```
print "Max speed:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.speed)
print "Max weight:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.weight)
print "Max acceleration:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.acceleration)
print "Max handling:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.handling)
print "Max drift:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.drift)
print "Max offroad:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.offroad)
print "Max turbo:", max(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.turbo)
print
print "Min speed:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.speed)
print "Min weight:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.weight)
print "Min acceleration:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.acceleration)
print "Min handling:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.handling)
print "Min drift:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.drift)
print "Min offroad:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.offroad)
print "Min turbo:", min(all_combinations, key=lambda c:c.stats.turbo)
```

The `min` and `max` functions provide a `key` argument for exactly this purpose. It takes a function that takes an item from the list and returns the value that you want to sort by. Here are the results:

```
Max speed: Funky Kong riding Aero Glider / Jetsetter (Stats(speed=73, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16))
Max weight: Bowser riding Piranha Prowler (Stats(speed=57, weight=72, acceleration=29, handling=35, drift=38, offroad=29, turbo=27))
Max acceleration: Toad riding Quacker (Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=73, handling=60, drift=68, offroad=48, turbo=57))
Max handling: Baby Mario riding Nano Bike / Bit Bike (Stats(speed=25, weight=26, acceleration=59, handling=73, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=62))
Max drift: Toad riding Bullet Bike (Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=38, handling=35, drift=73, offroad=29, turbo=67))
Max offroad: Toadette riding Magikruiser (Stats(speed=46, weight=24, acceleration=45, handling=45, drift=32, offroad=73, turbo=43))
Max turbo: Koopa Troopa riding Bullet Bike (Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=32, handling=38, drift=67, offroad=29, turbo=73))

Min speed: Baby Mario riding Nano Bike / Bit Bike (Stats(speed=25, weight=26, acceleration=59, handling=73, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=62))
Min weight: Toad riding Quacker (Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=73, handling=60, drift=68, offroad=48, turbo=57))
Min acceleration: Wario riding Flame Flyer (Stats(speed=62, weight=62, acceleration=16, handling=21, drift=48, offroad=21, turbo=54))
Min handling: Wario riding Aero Glider / Jetsetter (Stats(speed=69, weight=59, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=22))
Min drift: Wario riding Phantom (Stats(speed=43, weight=54, acceleration=43, handling=48, drift=17, offroad=59, turbo=46))
Min offroad: Donkey Kong riding Aero Glider / Jetsetter (Stats(speed=69, weight=59, acceleration=23, handling=19, drift=27, offroad=16, turbo=19))
Min turbo: Waluigi riding Aero Glider / Jetsetter (Stats(speed=69, weight=56, acceleration=27, handling=17, drift=32, offroad=19, turbo=16))
```

**Further ideas**

If you *do* want to apply this to much larger data sets, you could find the driver and vehicle with the min and max for each stat, and then for each stat combine the max driver with the max vehicle and the min driver with the min vehicle. That would be O(M log M + N log N) instead of O(M*N log M*N). But you would really need to be getting up to thousands of drivers and vehicles before I think this would be an issue.

If you want to apply this to massive data sets that won't even fit in memory, you could use generator expressions instead of list comprehensions. You would need to combine this with a parser that can read and yield one driver/vehicle at a time.

You could do more specific searches by adding constraints. For example, to find the fastest combination with turbo >= 50 and handling >= 40:

```
max((combination
    for combination in all_combinations
    if combination.stats.turbo >= 50
    and combination.stats.handling >= 40),
    key=lambda c:c.stats.speed)
```

If you want to get all those tied for top place, you could do something like this:

```
def all_max(sequence, key):
    top_value = key(max(sequence, key=key))
    return [item for item in sequence if key(item) == top_value]
```

Call it the same as you would call `max`. It returns a list of all those items tied for maximum value of whatever key specifies.

Comment: wow nice job! you finished before me too... (I got some multi-byte characters from that table when copy and paste to TextMate, and it was getting late). are you an avid Mario Kart player?... wonder if this will get some of our readers go play Mario Kart today too...

Comment: one thing that can add to is to find the max and min if there are multiple ways to have the max or min...  for example, if two different characters on different bikes or karts turn out having the same maximum speed, would be good to print them out both.

Answer (score 3):

Since there's not many characters and bikes, you could probably brute force it. That is, check every character with every available vehicle they can use and find the highest.

Comment: my question is what's not a clumsy and brute force way... also... even if there are many characters and bikes, you can still brute force it, can't you?

Comment: Yes, but it would take a long time.

Comment: Brute force it. The data set is so small it would take no time. You're not doing this for something other than Mario Kart, are you?

Answer (score 3):

I have extended @Weeble's answer in a couple of minor ways:

1. Pulls data directly from the Wikipedia page
2. Uses itertools.product instead of a custom make_combinations()
3. Automatically iterates through available attributes
4. Shows top-N and bottom-N items for each attribute for each rider size

.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import collections
import itertools

def value(s):
    "Parse string to integer (return 0 on bad string)"
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0

attrs = ('speed','weight','acceleration','handling','drift','offroad','turbo')
Stats = collections.namedtuple('Stats', attrs)
def add_stats(xs,ys):
    return Stats(*(x+y for x,y in zip(xs,ys)))

class ThingWithStats(object):
    def __init__(self, stats):
        super(ThingWithStats,self).__init__()
        self.stats = Stats(*stats)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stats)

class Driver(ThingWithStats):
    @classmethod
    def fromRow(cls,size,row):
        name  = row.th.getText().strip()
        stats = [value(col.getText()) for col in row.findAll('td')]
        return cls(name, size, stats)
    def __init__(self, name, size, stats):
        super(Driver,self).__init__(stats)
        self.name = name
        self.size = size
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0:32} ({1}): {2}".format(self.name, self.size, self.stats)

class Vehicle(ThingWithStats):
    @classmethod
    def fromRow(cls, size, kind, row):
        items = [col.getText() for col in row.findAll('td')]
        name  = items[0].strip()
        stats = [value(item) for item in items[1:8]]
        return cls(name, size, kind, stats)
    def __init__(self, name, size, kind, stats):
        super(Vehicle,self).__init__(stats)
        self.name     = name
        self.size     = size
        self.kind     = kind
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0:30} ({1} {2}): {3}".format(self.name, self.size, self.kind, self.stats)

class DrivenVehicle(ThingWithStats):
    def __init__(self, driver, vehicle):
        if driver.size != vehicle.size:
            raise ValueError('Driver {0} cannot fit vehicle {1}'.format(driver.name, vehicle.name))
        self.driver  = driver
        self.vehicle = vehicle
        self.stats   = add_stats(driver.stats, vehicle.stats)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} riding {1}: {2}".format(self.driver.name, self.vehicle.name, self.stats)

def getDrivers(table):
    rows  = table.findAll('tr')[2:]        # skip two header rows
    sizes = 'm'*8 + 's'*8 + 'l'*8 + 'sml'  # this is cheating a bit, but I don't see any way to get it from the table
    return [Driver.fromRow(size,row) for size,row in zip(sizes,rows)]

def getVehicles(table):
    sz = {'Small':'s', 'Medium':'m', 'Large':'l'}
    kd = {'Karts':'k', 'Bikes':'b'}
    size,kind = None,None
    cars = []
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        heads = row.findAll('th')
        if len(heads)==1:      # main table heading
            pass
        elif len(heads)==10:   # sub-heading
            s,k = heads[0].getText().strip().split()
            size,kind = sz[s], kd[k]
        else:                  # data
            cars.append(Vehicle.fromRow(size,kind,row))
    return cars

def getData():
    url = 'http://www.mariowiki.com/Mario_Kart_Wii'    # page to look at
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()                 # get raw html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)                         # parse

    drivers = []
    cars = []
    for table in soup.findAll('table'):                # look at all tables in page
        try:
            head = table.th.getText()
            if 'Character Bonuses' in head:
                drivers = getDrivers(table)
            elif 'Vehicle Stats' in head:
                cars = getVehicles(table)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

    return drivers,cars

def binBy(attr, lst):
    res = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for item in lst:
        res[getattr(item,attr)].append(item)
    return res

def main():
    drivers,cars = getData()

    drivers = binBy('size', drivers)
    cars    = binBy('size', cars)

    sizes = list(set(drivers.keys()) & set(cars.keys()))
    sizes.sort()

    combos  = {}
    for size in sizes:
        combos[size] = [DrivenVehicle(driver,car) for driver,car in itertools.product(drivers[size], cars[size])]

    topN = 3
    for attr in attrs:
        print "By {0}:".format(attr)
        for size in sizes:
            combos[size].sort(key=lambda dv: getattr(dv.stats,attr), reverse=True)
            print "  ({0})".format(size)
            for dv in combos[size][:topN]:
                print '    '+str(dv)
            print '    ...'
            for dv in combos[size][-topN:]:
                print '    '+str(dv)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

and the final results:

```
By speed:
  (l)
    Funky Kong riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=73, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16)
    Rosalina riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=72, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=20, drift=27, offroad=16, turbo=19)
    Large Mii riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=72, weight=56, acceleration=24, handling=20, drift=30, offroad=16, turbo=19)
    ...
    Donkey Kong riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=37, weight=62, acceleration=53, handling=58, drift=21, offroad=45, turbo=51)
    King Boo riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=37, weight=59, acceleration=51, handling=61, drift=21, offroad=48, turbo=48)
    Dry Bowser riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=37, weight=59, acceleration=51, handling=56, drift=21, offroad=51, turbo=54)
  (m)
    Daisy riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=68, weight=48, acceleration=27, handling=26, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=27)
    Medium Mii riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=67, weight=51, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=24, turbo=27)
    Luigi riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=66, weight=54, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=24)
    ...
    Birdo riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=35, acceleration=54, handling=62, drift=35, offroad=54, turbo=61)
    Diddy Kong riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=32, acceleration=57, handling=62, drift=38, offroad=51, turbo=61)
    Bowser Jr. riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=32, acceleration=54, handling=62, drift=35, offroad=54, turbo=59)
  (s)
    Baby Luigi riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=37, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    Baby Daisy riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=35, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=32)
    Baby Peach riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=63, weight=35, acceleration=38, handling=32, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    ...
    Toad riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=25, weight=18, acceleration=65, handling=67, drift=46, offroad=56, turbo=62)
    Koopa Troopa riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=25, weight=18, acceleration=59, handling=70, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=68)
    Dry Bones riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=25, weight=18, acceleration=62, handling=67, drift=43, offroad=56, turbo=68)
By weight:
  (l)
    Bowser riding Piranha Prowler: Stats(speed=57, weight=72, acceleration=29, handling=35, drift=38, offroad=29, turbo=27)
    Wario riding Piranha Prowler: Stats(speed=55, weight=70, acceleration=29, handling=35, drift=35, offroad=32, turbo=33)
    Donkey Kong riding Piranha Prowler: Stats(speed=55, weight=70, acceleration=31, handling=37, drift=35, offroad=29, turbo=30)
    ...
    Waluigi riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=48, acceleration=35, handling=32, drift=64, offroad=30, turbo=59)
    King Boo riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=48, acceleration=29, handling=37, drift=59, offroad=30, turbo=59)
    Dry Bowser riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=48, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=59, offroad=33, turbo=65)
  (m)
    Luigi riding Wild Wing: Stats(speed=59, weight=57, acceleration=21, handling=29, drift=59, offroad=24, turbo=59)
    Mario riding Wild Wing: Stats(speed=57, weight=57, acceleration=23, handling=31, drift=62, offroad=24, turbo=59)
    Luigi riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=66, weight=54, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=24)
    ...
    Peach riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=34, weight=32, acceleration=59, handling=62, drift=41, offroad=51, turbo=56)
    Diddy Kong riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=32, acceleration=57, handling=62, drift=38, offroad=51, turbo=61)
    Bowser Jr. riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=32, acceleration=54, handling=62, drift=35, offroad=54, turbo=59)
  (s)
    Baby Luigi riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=51, weight=43, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=64, turbo=40)
    Baby Mario riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=46, weight=43, acceleration=43, handling=49, drift=29, offroad=64, turbo=40)
    Baby Daisy riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=51, weight=41, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=64, turbo=43)
    ...
    Toad riding Quacker: Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=73, handling=60, drift=68, offroad=48, turbo=57)
    Koopa Troopa riding Quacker: Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=67, handling=63, drift=62, offroad=48, turbo=63)
    Dry Bones riding Quacker: Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=70, handling=60, drift=65, offroad=48, turbo=63)
By acceleration:
  (l)
    Waluigi riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=37, weight=59, acceleration=57, handling=56, drift=26, offroad=48, turbo=48)
    Waluigi riding Offroader: Stats(speed=39, weight=64, acceleration=54, handling=54, drift=23, offroad=46, turbo=45)
    Large Mii riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=40, weight=59, acceleration=54, handling=59, drift=24, offroad=45, turbo=51)
    ...
    Rosalina riding Flame Flyer: Stats(speed=65, weight=59, acceleration=16, handling=24, drift=48, offroad=18, turbo=51)
    King Boo riding Flame Flyer: Stats(speed=62, weight=59, acceleration=16, handling=26, drift=48, offroad=21, turbo=48)
    Dry Bowser riding Flame Flyer: Stats(speed=62, weight=59, acceleration=16, handling=21, drift=48, offroad=24, turbo=54)
  (m)
    Peach riding Nostalgia 1/ Classic Dragster: Stats(speed=39, weight=43, acceleration=64, handling=54, drift=60, offroad=40, turbo=51)
    Diddy Kong riding Nostalgia 1/ Classic Dragster: Stats(speed=37, weight=43, acceleration=62, handling=54, drift=57, offroad=40, turbo=56)
    Mario riding Nostalgia 1/ Classic Dragster: Stats(speed=37, weight=49, acceleration=61, handling=56, drift=57, offroad=40, turbo=51)
    ...
    Birdo riding Wild Wing: Stats(speed=57, weight=54, acceleration=21, handling=29, drift=59, offroad=27, turbo=64)
    Daisy riding Wild Wing: Stats(speed=61, weight=51, acceleration=21, handling=31, drift=59, offroad=24, turbo=62)
    Bowser Jr. riding Wild Wing: Stats(speed=57, weight=51, acceleration=21, handling=29, drift=59, offroad=27, turbo=62)
  (s)
    Toad riding Quacker: Stats(speed=32, weight=17, acceleration=73, handling=60, drift=68, offroad=48, turbo=57)
    Toad riding Cheep Charger: Stats(speed=34, weight=24, acceleration=70, handling=56, drift=65, offroad=45, turbo=54)
    Baby Peach riding Quacker: Stats(speed=35, weight=23, acceleration=70, handling=63, drift=62, offroad=48, turbo=57)
    ...
    Small Mii riding Concerto/ Mini Beast: Stats(speed=58, weight=35, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=67, offroad=27, turbo=67)
    Toadette riding Concerto/ Mini Beast: Stats(speed=58, weight=32, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=64, offroad=33, turbo=64)
    Koopa Troopa riding Concerto/ Mini Beast: Stats(speed=55, weight=32, acceleration=29, handling=35, drift=64, offroad=27, turbo=70)
By handling:
  (l)
    King Boo riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=37, weight=59, acceleration=51, handling=61, drift=21, offroad=48, turbo=48)
    Large Mii riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=40, weight=59, acceleration=54, handling=59, drift=24, offroad=45, turbo=51)
    Rosalina riding Wario Bike: Stats(speed=40, weight=59, acceleration=51, handling=59, drift=21, offroad=45, turbo=51)
    ...
    Wario riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=69, weight=59, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=22)
    Funky Kong riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=73, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16)
    Dry Bowser riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=69, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=22, turbo=22)
  (m)
    Mario riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=32, weight=38, acceleration=56, handling=64, drift=38, offroad=51, turbo=56)
    Daisy riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=36, weight=32, acceleration=54, handling=64, drift=35, offroad=51, turbo=59)
    Peach riding Bon Bon/ Sugarscoot: Stats(speed=34, weight=32, acceleration=59, handling=62, drift=41, offroad=51, turbo=56)
    ...
    Yoshi riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=64, weight=51, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=40, offroad=26, turbo=24)
    Birdo riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=64, weight=51, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    Bowser Jr. riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=64, weight=48, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=24, turbo=27)
  (s)
    Baby Mario riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=25, weight=26, acceleration=59, handling=73, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=62)
    Baby Peach riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=28, weight=24, acceleration=62, handling=70, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=62)
    Koopa Troopa riding Nano Bike/ Bit Bike: Stats(speed=25, weight=18, acceleration=59, handling=70, drift=40, offroad=56, turbo=68)
    ...
    Baby Daisy riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=35, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=32)
    Small Mii riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=63, weight=32, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=46, offroad=24, turbo=32)
    Toadette riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=63, weight=29, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=30, turbo=29)
By drift:
  (l)
    Waluigi riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=48, acceleration=35, handling=32, drift=64, offroad=30, turbo=59)
    Large Mii riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=53, weight=48, acceleration=32, handling=35, drift=62, offroad=27, turbo=62)
    Bowser riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=52, weight=53, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=62, offroad=27, turbo=59)
    ...
    Wario riding Phantom: Stats(speed=43, weight=54, acceleration=43, handling=48, drift=17, offroad=59, turbo=46)
    Funky Kong riding Phantom: Stats(speed=47, weight=51, acceleration=43, handling=48, drift=17, offroad=59, turbo=40)
    Dry Bowser riding Phantom: Stats(speed=43, weight=51, acceleration=43, handling=48, drift=17, offroad=62, turbo=46)
  (m)
    Peach riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=57, weight=37, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=68, offroad=27, turbo=62)
    Mario riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=55, weight=43, acceleration=26, handling=34, drift=65, offroad=27, turbo=62)
    Diddy Kong riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=55, weight=37, acceleration=27, handling=32, drift=65, offroad=27, turbo=67)
    ...
    Medium Mii riding Turbo Blooper/ Super Blooper: Stats(speed=53, weight=43, acceleration=35, handling=37, drift=21, offroad=57, turbo=38)
    Birdo riding Turbo Blooper/ Super Blooper: Stats(speed=50, weight=43, acceleration=35, handling=37, drift=21, offroad=57, turbo=40)
    Bowser Jr. riding Turbo Blooper/ Super Blooper: Stats(speed=50, weight=40, acceleration=35, handling=37, drift=21, offroad=57, turbo=38)
  (s)
    Toad riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=38, handling=35, drift=73, offroad=29, turbo=67)
    Dry Bones riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=35, handling=35, drift=70, offroad=29, turbo=73)
    Small Mii riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=56, weight=27, acceleration=32, handling=35, drift=70, offroad=29, turbo=70)
    ...
    Baby Luigi riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=51, weight=43, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=64, turbo=40)
    Baby Daisy riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=51, weight=41, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=64, turbo=43)
    Toadette riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=49, weight=35, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=70, turbo=40)
By offroad:
  (l)
    Dry Bowser riding Phantom: Stats(speed=43, weight=51, acceleration=43, handling=48, drift=17, offroad=62, turbo=46)
    Waluigi riding Phantom: Stats(speed=43, weight=51, acceleration=49, handling=48, drift=22, offroad=59, turbo=40)
    King Boo riding Phantom: Stats(speed=43, weight=51, acceleration=43, handling=53, drift=17, offroad=59, turbo=40)
    ...
    Bowser riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=71, weight=61, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=30, offroad=16, turbo=16)
    Rosalina riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=72, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=20, drift=27, offroad=16, turbo=19)
    Donkey Kong riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=69, weight=59, acceleration=23, handling=19, drift=27, offroad=16, turbo=19)
  (m)
    Yoshi riding Rapide/ Zip Zip: Stats(speed=41, weight=38, acceleration=45, handling=51, drift=32, offroad=67, turbo=45)
    Medium Mii riding Rapide/ Zip Zip: Stats(speed=44, weight=38, acceleration=45, handling=51, drift=29, offroad=65, turbo=48)
    Birdo riding Rapide/ Zip Zip: Stats(speed=41, weight=38, acceleration=45, handling=51, drift=29, offroad=65, turbo=50)
    ...
    Diddy Kong riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=64, weight=48, acceleration=30, handling=24, drift=40, offroad=21, turbo=29)
    Daisy riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=68, weight=48, acceleration=27, handling=26, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=27)
    Luigi riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=66, weight=54, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=24)
  (s)
    Toadette riding Magikruiser: Stats(speed=46, weight=24, acceleration=45, handling=45, drift=32, offroad=73, turbo=43)
    Toadette riding Rally Romper/ Tiny Titan: Stats(speed=49, weight=35, acceleration=43, handling=43, drift=29, offroad=70, turbo=40)
    Toad riding Magikruiser: Stats(speed=43, weight=24, acceleration=51, handling=45, drift=38, offroad=67, turbo=43)
    ...
    Koopa Troopa riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=60, weight=29, acceleration=35, handling=32, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=35)
    Baby Luigi riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=37, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    Baby Daisy riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=35, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=32)
By turbo:
  (l)
    Dry Bowser riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=48, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=59, offroad=33, turbo=65)
    Wario riding Twinkle Star/ Shooting Star: Stats(speed=50, weight=51, acceleration=29, handling=32, drift=59, offroad=30, turbo=65)
    Dry Bowser riding Dragonetti/ Honeycoupe: Stats(speed=53, weight=62, acceleration=27, handling=29, drift=56, offroad=30, turbo=62)
    ...
    King Boo riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=69, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=22, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16)
    Funky Kong riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=73, weight=56, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=27, offroad=19, turbo=16)
    Bowser riding Aero Glider/ Jetsetter: Stats(speed=71, weight=61, acceleration=21, handling=17, drift=30, offroad=16, turbo=16)
  (m)
    Birdo riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=55, weight=40, acceleration=24, handling=32, drift=62, offroad=30, turbo=67)
    Diddy Kong riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=55, weight=37, acceleration=27, handling=32, drift=65, offroad=27, turbo=67)
    Medium Mii riding Mach Bike: Stats(speed=58, weight=40, acceleration=24, handling=32, drift=62, offroad=30, turbo=65)
    ...
    Peach riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=66, weight=48, acceleration=32, handling=24, drift=43, offroad=21, turbo=24)
    Mario riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=64, weight=54, acceleration=29, handling=26, drift=40, offroad=21, turbo=24)
    Luigi riding B Dasher Mk. 2/ Sprinter: Stats(speed=66, weight=54, acceleration=27, handling=24, drift=37, offroad=21, turbo=24)
  (s)
    Dry Bones riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=35, handling=35, drift=70, offroad=29, turbo=73)
    Koopa Troopa riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=53, weight=24, acceleration=32, handling=38, drift=67, offroad=29, turbo=73)
    Small Mii riding Bullet Bike: Stats(speed=56, weight=27, acceleration=32, handling=35, drift=70, offroad=29, turbo=70)
    ...
    Baby Mario riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=60, weight=37, acceleration=35, handling=35, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    Baby Peach riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=63, weight=35, acceleration=38, handling=32, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
    Baby Luigi riding Blue Falcon: Stats(speed=65, weight=37, acceleration=35, handling=29, drift=43, offroad=24, turbo=29)
```